# Interploating list using python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, interpolation

I have set list of x and y, for example

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
y=[1,4,9,16,25,36]
```

and I need to find the y values for a set of u defined as

```
u = [[2,3,1],[4,2,1],[6,3,2],[2,4,5],[2,3,6]]
```

I am using [this interpolation module](http://proj.badc.rl.ac.uk/svn/dcip/ddp/branches/ddp-dev/tasks/ddp12/interp.py). It is similar to the numpy interpolate

Currently, I follow:

```
v = [interp(x,y,u[i]) for i in range(len(k))]
```

Is there a way to circumvent the for loop, because It increases my computational time.
I could rather spare my memory instead of time. My list size are very huge!
I hope that inbuilt map function could be used, but not aware of how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map()` loops internally too - it just does it C-side where it is faster. However, you are already using a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw), which also offloads to C and will probably be faster than `map()`.

That said, there is an opportunity to gain speed and readability here by changing your loop:

```
v = [interp(x, y, i) for i in u]
```

In Python, we loop over iterators, not indices. By indirectly looping as you were, you will slow your looping down significantly. It also makes it far less readable.

As to using `map()`, it could be done using [`functools.partial()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to make a function that calls `interp()` with `x` and `y` prefilled:

```
import functools
f = functools.partial(interp, x, y)
v = list(map(f, u))
```

However, as I said before, this will likely be slower, and is far less readable.

(I use the term C-side in this answer presuming you are using CPython, but in any other implementation, it will also be implemented more efficiently, using whatever lower-level options are available).

Comment: Thank to remind me that, I could use the list comprehension like that, it doesn't improve the speed much. If i modify the interp module to handle the input shape by using broadcasting(I usually think that it is synonymous to the vector operations) will my speed imporve

Comment: I don't know the maths of it, I'm afraid. I would imagine you are right in that the expense of the operation is in the computation and not the loop.

Comment: You are right, the interp module takes approx 0.02s for 1 call with the len(x)=len(y)=100 and the the len(u[0])=1280 and if i loop it for say 1000 times it is drastically slow. So, If I could change the interp module such that it handles a 2D list, will the time be reduced reasonalbly

Comment: That entirely depends on how you implement that change. The best answer is to try it and see.

Comment: partial does not pass the variables properly to the interp module, can you please explain how to use partial, this seems to be a quite good solution.

Comment: As I stated in the post, ``partial()`` and ``map()`` are a *worse* way to do this than a list comprehension. As to *partial does not pass the variables properly* - in what way? I linked to the documentation for ``partial()`` in the post, which explains it in detail.

Comment: It doesn't significantly improve the time, rather the case gets worse, but it's a good suggesition. I have eited 'v=list(map(f, u))' then it works.

Comment: In your question, you use `u` in your explanation, but then `k` in your example, I followed your example.